# How to identify established but inactive SSH tunnel

Tags: powershell, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I created a reverse SSH tunnel from a public server to my local Windows Machine. It works properly and I can access my local machine. However, due to internet disruption, the tunnel disconnects but doesn't come up when internet connectivity resumes. I checked on windows that the ssh process was still running and the connection was shown established.

```
>> Get-Process ssh | select -expandproperty ProcessName
ssh
```

`Get-NetTCPConnection` also showing Established Internet on port 22.

The tunnel is though not accessible from public server

```
$ ssh user@localhost -p 2000
ssh: connect to host localhost port 2000: Connection refused
```

How can I identify whether SSH tunnel is inactive or not so that I can kill it and restart new. Any command line solution will do for me except autossh as its not available for windows.